# When 6- is rolled on harm, does the MC still make a move?

Tags: the-sprawl

When a player rolls harm, the 10+ results are worse than the 7-9 results. The description explicitly says that the results are reversed, low is successful, high is complicated. Does this mean that on a 6-, you simply take the harm and there's no other effect? Or do you take the harm and the MC also makes a move?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The consequences of taking harm are included in the harm roll itself. Don't do an additional "hard move" here.**

I think this is a bit muddled in the text, which doesn't write specific miss consequences into most moves.

Note the MC Moves section on page 173:

> The MC gets to make a move:
>
> » When a player misses a move
>
> » When the players are waiting passively for something to happen
>
> » When the fiction demands it

I'd suggest deferring to this passage since it's the most detailed explanation of how and why to make MC moves. Other parts of the text uses "6-" to refer to a miss, but in the harm roll's case, "6-" is explicitly *not* a miss.

*However*, don't rush to do a hard move on a "10+" on harm, either. The listed consequences are already pretty harsh, which tends to prompt a response. If the players seem stuck or drag their feet, then do an MC move (because they're "waiting passively for something to happen," or because "the fiction demands it" if we've already established that they're cornered or in a precarious position or tight on time). If they react immediately, they probably have enough on their plate already that moves will snowball naturally without turning the screws when they take harm.

---

(To be honest, I'm working backwards here: I "know" that you shouldn't need to do a hard move after harm, on the basis of how Apocalypse World works, and I'm trying to find a coherent explanation for why this applies to The Sprawl. In other words, I'm operating under the assumption that if a major deviation from "normal for PbtA" was intended here, the author would have spelled it out more clearly.)

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I was under the impression that moves happened on every 6-, and didn't realize the difference between that and a miss.

Comment: @emma I think the most important thing is that Moves Snowball. The "MC move on a miss" rule plays into that by making sure you get interesting escalation instead of just "whiffing" on a miss like some games do. But honestly, if you misfire from time to time (e.g. your MC move just ends up being some fluffy narration that goes nowhere), the rest of the game corrects for that.